# .NET Memory Profiler - Native memory shows large "Other data" memory consumption

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I am using [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) v4.6 to analyze a dump file created by Windows 7 Task Manager.
If I remember correctly the process had about 450 MB memory alloced before dumping it into a file and about 600 MB after it.

The process is running as Windows Service on a long-term simulation, constantly sending data via .NET Remoting. The memory is increasing at about 40MB per hour at full usage.

The Native memory tab shows me a usage of 470 MB private bytes and 130 MB potentially shared.
I expect the potentially shared bytes to be generated by the dumping process, so I ignored it for now.
The thread stacks are also increasing, but as the thread count stays the same, I expect that memory increase to be finite.

A noticable high amount, 450 MB, of that private bytes are filed under "Other data".
I do not understand what [this definition](http://memprofiler.com/OnlineDocs/default.htm?turl=otherdata.htm) is trying to say me, so can someone explain what "Other data" is and what could cause this permanently memory increase.

Comment: @HansPassant, .NET Memory Profiler is free? When? Where? How? Tell me, so I can get it quickly...

Comment: Could you try to use VMMap on this process? It can show you memory usage more clearly.

Comment: What should I look for using VMMap? I can see that 140 MB of 190 MB private bytes are held by Heap. But I'm not sure how to use that tool correctly. Note that I have analyzed another instance of that application, because VMMap is not able to work with memory dumps, so the data will diverge from above.

Comment: Sorry to bump this old question, but did you ever find more details about the issue? What was causing the native memory consumption? We have a very similar problem, but are unable to further analyze the memory grouped as "other data" in .NET memory profiler.